# Set contentMode of placeholder image with AlamofireImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, alamofire, alamofireimage

I'm using AlamofireImage and I noticed it has a feature of setting content type of the desired image. However, I do not see the possibility of setting up the content type of the placeholder image itself.

For example, right now in my `cellForRow` method I'm doing:

```
let filter = AspectScaledToFillSizeFilter(size: cell.myPhoto.frame.size) 
 cell.myPhoto.af_setImage(
     withURL: URL(string: data.photo)!,
     placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholderImg"),
     filter: filter,
     imageTransition: .crossDissolve(0.2)
 )
```

Is there a way of setting e.g. content mode = `center` only on placeholder image, while keeping `AspectScaledToFillSizeFilter` content mode of the original image?

Answer (score 3):

What about setting the `contentMode` of the image view to `.center` before fetching the image, and in the completion block reset the `contentMode` to `.scaleToFill` (the default `contentMode` of a `UIImageView`)?

```
cell.myPhoto.contentMode = .center
cell.myPhoto.af_setImage(withURL: imageURL, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "placeholderImg"), filter: filter, completion: { (response) in
    cell.myPhoto.contentMode = .scaleToFill
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Dwonload image with a palceholder image in **Swift 3- Alamofire 3**

```
  cell.myPhoto.af_setImage(withURL: url!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "handi.jpg"), filter: nil, progress: nil, progressQueue: DispatchQueue.main, imageTransition: .noTransition, runImageTransitionIfCached: false) { (response) in

}
```